# XMLHttpRequest formatting issue

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The following code is used to connect to an API and get data.

```
function req() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "https://url/api");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", "1234");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "1234");

    xhr.send();
}
```

The function is called via a button
The API is confirmed working with postman. Firefox displays the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The interesting problem is that when inspecting with Firefox, the set headers seem to be misaligned

```
Host: url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers:  uid,x-api-key
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

I can edit this in Firefox to the correct way:

```
Host: url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
uid: 1234
x-api-key: 1234
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And will get successful state **200**

What could be the issue of wrong formatting when using js?

Comment: What is the leading character here: `" uid"` Space?

Comment: It's not wrong formatting. The server is not sending back an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so the browser will not allow JavaScript to access any content.

Comment: i've edited this in question.
But why is the problem fixed when i reformat the request in firefox? And also working in Postman (API Tester)? If this is a server error, shouldn't it refuse to work always?